# Amend a past commit from a previously merged branch, while keeping branch history

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

## Problem

Say that I have done some work on `master`:

```
c1 <- c2
       ^
     master
```

At this point, I branch off, and do some more work:

```
                test                  
                 v
          c3 <- c4
c1 <- c2 /
       ^   
     master
```

Then do a `git merge --no-ff` (`--no-ff` to keep the branch history):

```
                test                  
                 v
          c3 <- c4
c1 <- c2 /        \ [c5]
                      ^   
                    master
```

(`[c5]` is a merge commit)

I then delete the `test` branch, thinking that I have finished with it. However, I find that, after all, there is a problem with the work I've done on `test`. I need to amend `c3`, but **without harming the branch history.**

---

## Things that I've tried

### My attempt

I `git checkout c3`; then change what I need to change, and then `git commit --amend`. Then I `checkout` the `master` branch, and `git branch temp c3`. I then `git rebase --preserve-merges temp`: this gives me a merge conflict, which I fix, and then `git add <file>` and `git rebase --continue`.

However, when I look at the branch history with `git log --oneline --graph`, I see something like the following:

```
*  [c5]
|\
| * c4
|/
* c3'
* c2
* c1
```

It should look more like this:

```
*  [c5]
|\
| * c4
| * c3'
|/
* c2
* c1
```

where `c3'` is the amended commit.

How can I get this behaviour out of `git`?

### Tim's suggestion

```
git checkout c3
git checkout -b test
git commit --amend
git checkout master
git reset --hard c2
git merge --no-ff test
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, as we lose `c4`. (Please correct me, Tim, if I'm misinterpreting your answer.) The resulting branch history from `git log --oneline --graph` is as follows:

```
*  [c5]
|\  
| * c3'
|/  
* c2
* c1
```

where `[c5']` is a new merge commit. (I don't mind that it's new, by the way.)

Comment: Did you try just branching off c3 and merging to master?

Comment: Is this just your local master? Or have you pushed anything >= c3?

Comment: `git checkout c3` will enter a "detached header"　status, make modification on this status is not recommended. If you want to modify commit history, you should use `git rebase -i`

Comment: Just my local master, @Massey101; nothing has (yet) been pushed to a remote.

Comment: @Tim (and all other viewers): I have made a bash script for making a test repo identical to the hypothetical one in the question. You can find it here, on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/danieloosthuizen/f9009b65ce9d833b268c

Comment: I don't want to embed it into the question, as it's already long enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appear to have found an answer! Thank you, Tim, for the inspiration to try an `--interactive` rebase.

Basically, the answer lies in doing a `git rebase -p -i <root>`; I'm calling the commit right before where the branch history forks the `<root>`. In the hypothetical case of the question, the `<root>` is `c2`.

The `-p` is shorthand for `--preserve-merges`, which will stop `git rebase` from removing merge commits.

An editor will pop up with something like the following:

```
pick c3 <message>
pick c4 <message>
pick [c5] <message>
```

Change the `pick` before `c3` to `edit` so that you have:

```
edit c3 <message>
pick c4 <message>
pick [c5] <message>
```

Save and quit. Make the changes that you want to make, add them, and `git commit --amend`. After this, you need to `git rebase --continue` to continue the rebase.

You may get merge conflicts during this time. Just fix the conflicts, `git add` the changed files to mark the conflict as fixed, then `git rebase --continue`. Repeat this until `git` tells you that the rebase has been successful.

Comment: oh ya, I forgot the -p. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks @Tim; your answers (and patience) helped a *lot*, though!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interactive rebase:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i c2
```

This should open an editor with one line per commit. Change the `pick` in `c3`'s line to `edit`. Save and close. Now git rewinds you back to `c3` and will stop there for you to make an edit. Change what you want to change and amend with

```
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: When the editor opened, it only showed me the line `pick c4 <message>`; after I aborted the rebase, it seemed to have flattened the branch history.

Comment: @digitalis_ sorry, I made a mistake. Updated my answer (`git rebase -i c3`). For your flattened branch history: that's weird, an aborted rebase should not do anything. I hope you can restore it somehow?

Comment: Don't worry @Tim, I was using a test repository – no data was lost. I seem to have found an answer to my question using an interactive rebase, as you suggested. Thanks for the help!

Comment: with regards to the weird flattening: I think I must have `:wq`ed and then `git rebase --abort`ed, which may have been the cause of the flattening.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your question, when you make c4 commit in test branch and merge it to master branch, fast-forward mode will only move master reference to c4, why do you think you will lost the branch history and use --no-ff option purposely?

About what you have tried, It seems that you made modification to timeline of master branch timeline, so the commit graph is a obvious consequence.